# use instance in foreignkey

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a model shop, product

### shop

```
class Shop(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, related_name='shop', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True, default='shop', )
        address = models.CharField(max_length=70, null=True)
```

### products

```
class Product(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

user log in as a shop and when he wants to insert a new product then user.shop=product.shop[image] that shown I in image

Comment: Basically you want the product to be added as per the login in user.

Comment: I explain again you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the views.py

```
def CreateProduct(request):
    shops = request.user.shop
    form = ProductForm(initial={'shop': shops})
```